# How do I get the web_gantt chart module in odoo9 version?

Tags: odoo-9

I am using odoo9 version, I have installed and run the web_gantt v8 module in v9..but I am unable to see the web_gantt chart module in my local machine....but the module is installed...

Please let me know how do i get the gantt chart in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

currently web_gantt module not available for Odoo 9 Community version. just look this link. --> Link